# How to move and scale image while doing parallax effect?

Tags: android

I want to move and scale profile image to `1/4th of app_bar_height` and then move and scale it vertically till `1/2 of app_bar_height`. So when parallax effect will complete then my profile_image will be shown at center of `AppBarLayout` and when it collapsed it will be at start of toolbar.

**Here is my xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/quila2"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_image_initial_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_image_initial_size"
                android:src="@drawable/quila" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:text="@string/large_text" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: use scaleType = "matrix" in `de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView` assuming it extends `ImageView`

Comment: I guess, you need to wire up imageview's scaling to NestedScrollView's scroll event..

Answer (score 1):

You can set `ScaleType="MATRIX"` A `Matrix` is constructed and scaled based on the user’s pinch gesture scale factor and then the `ImageView` set based on this scaled Matrix.

Please visit here [Android ImageView ScaleType](http://milkmidi.blogspot.in/2011/09/android-imageview-scaletype.html)

Finally

```
 <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_image_initial_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_image_initial_size"
            android:src="@drawable/quila"
            android:scaleType="matrix" />
```

Comment: add `android:adjustViewBounds="true" `

Comment: I want to move whole image from toolbar to AppBarLayout center, So these things will not work

Answer (score 0):

To move image with parallax effect, we need to implement custom behavior provided by CoordinatorLayout.Behavior(View) class in design library. Here View will be (CircleImageView).

It has two functions:

```
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, CircleImageView child, View dependency) {
    return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout; // here dependency is the view on which child has depends
}
```

and

```
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, CircleImageView child, View dependency) {
return true; //if child has changed
}
```

So you can move circularImageView with appBarLayout changes.